# matching data from sql and assigned them to echarts

Tags: php, mysql, echarts

**This is my sql query**

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(C.created_date) as date_label, COUNT(C.consignment_id) as deliveries, C.service_id, CS.display_name
FROM (`consignments` as C)
LEFT JOIN `courier_service` as CS ON `CS`.`id`=`C`.`service_id`
WHERE `C`.`org_id` =  165
AND (created_date >= '2017-06-25' AND created_date <= '2017-12-13')
AND `C`.`is_deleted` =  0
AND `C`.`is_service_assigned` =  1
GROUP BY `date_label`, `C`.`service_id`
```

[This is my query results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu6LW.png)

I am creating a line chart with echarts. What should i do in order to match the data in my php controller so that [0] which is monday have 3 deliveries ?

My php code

```
$label = array();
$weektrendlist = array();
foreach($services as $service) {
    $listname = array("0" => 0, "1" => 0, "2" => 0, "3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0, "6" => 0);

    $weektrendinfobyservice = $this->overall_reports_model-> overall_performance_week_trend_per_service($service->service_id, $start_date, $end_date, $org_id);

    foreach($weektrendinfobyservice as $row) {
        $listname[$row->date_label] = $row->deliveries;
    }
    $dataset = array();
    $dataset['name'] = $service->display_name;
    $hash = md5($service->service_id.$service->service_name);

    $dataset['data'] = array_values($listname);
    $weektrendlist[] = $dataset;
}
$result['weektrend'] = array(
    "label" => array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
    "datasets" => $weektrendlist
);
```